# how to specify which branch gets build in jenkins from a webhook in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I installed the bitbucket plugin in Jenkins, and made the following changes:

- I added the webhook on the bitbucket repo in the following format:

  http://JENKINS.SERVER:PORT/bitbucket-hook

  - Under build trigger enabled `Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket`
  - Under `Source Code Management selected GIT`; I defined which branch to build: **foobar**

So my question is, I want the build to be triggered **only** when there is a commit on that specific branch **foobar**!

How do I do that?

Do I need to specify anything else on the bitbucket side?

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom! I just had the same question. I was wondering if you were able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In Job Configuration -> Source Code Management -> Branches to build

Specify which branch you want to trigger for build